# Neovim Terminal shows a different list of programs available in /usr/bin

Tags: neovim, terminal

I have installed [Neovim via flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.neovim.nvim) on Fedora 34.

I use the `coc.nvim` plugin for Neovim, it complains that it can't find 'node'. However I have installed node and it is in `/usr/bin/node`. To double check this I went into the Neovim terminal and typed `which node` - but there it doesn't find it at all.

This then gets more curious because if I run a side by side `ls` of `/usr/bin` inside Neovim terminal and in gnome-terminal I get two completely different lists - note: this is just for all the `n*` binaries in `/usr/bin`

[image]

Comment: @BLayer thanks for your comment. I see `/usr/bin` for both. nvim terminal: `[ io.neovim.nvim bin]$ /usr/bin/pwd \n  /usr/bin`,  gnome terminal: `[ian@stafke bin]$ /usr/bin/pwd \n /usr/bin`

Comment: The `ls -l` command is also curious, it gives this example output: `-rwxr-xr-x 5 nfsnobody nfsnobody   37176 May 15 12:26 namei` - it has `nfsnobody` as the owner and group of the file when it should be `root`

Comment: This is a new install as of yesterday, the only thing that is different from how I've done it before is using flatpak. There's no docker or VMs involved. When starting neovim it is run via `flatpak run io.neovim.nvim` - I can only think that is doing something

Comment: Oh, I don't know anything about that but just read that includes a **sandbox** feature. That must be what's causing it. It's running in something like a chroot environment I assume. Fully isolated from your main environment...and not fully emulating that environment it seems.

Comment: Hmm - [Neovim issue #14543](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/14543) seems seems relevant *"/usr/bin and there a like are not accessible from within the flatpak"*

Comment: Ah, yes that does sound relevant.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Neovim issue #14543](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/14543) this appears to be a consequence of using Flatpak.

> after installing the flatpak io.neovim.nvim you can't run e.g. :terminal or say !latexmk as /usr/bin and there a like are not accessible from within the flatpak.

I switched back to the regular `dnf` package for Neovim and the problem goes away.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that I wouldn't call this an "issue" of Flatpak but rather a limitation of distributing software as Flatpak. Flatpak is an application container and, as such, limiting access to the binaries installed on your system is part of what it does. So that's pretty much by design. If you need to have your Neovim access other binaries installed in your system, you're much better with a native build such as the one you can get through dnf.

Comment: @filbranden fair point - I've changed the text